# Brand store Logo not showing in email

Tags: image, email-templates, magento-2.2.5

I have configured the concerned brand logo to the store theme under the **Email Transaction section**[image]

After saving the configuration, I flushed the cache and re-indexed. Then I created a customer, with all the required fields and the Welcome mail is sent to him / her. But the Email template showed a broken Brand image logo.

[image]

When I tried to open that broken image, I got this below error

[image]

Please help me how to resolve this issue.....

Comment: I am using Mageplaza Smtp configuration for sending the mail

Comment: Check image is exist or not. If any theme then `/pub/static/frontend/Module/<Theme>/en_US/Magento_Email/`

Comment: No, the uploaded images are not there in the path.

My path is **pub/static/frontend/TemplateMonster/theme007/en_US/Magento_Email**

Comment: Can you set your custom theme in admin panel?

Comment: Yes, I am able to set custom theme in admin panel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80323/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-manjunath-pv).